# TypeScript: Splice Value from array throws Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, for-loop

I want to remove a Value from an array.

My Code is runnign fine, but Visual Studio Code indicates that there is a Problem:

My Code:

```js
removeFromFav(){
        var favoritesArray : Array<any> = this.getFavorites()
        for(let key in favoritesArray){
            if(favoritesArray[key].hidx === this.hidx && favoritesArray[key].kontenrahmen === this.kontenrahmen ) {
                favoritesArray.splice(key, 1);
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem( this.storageName, JSON.stringify(favoritesArray) );
    }
```

Error Message:

> No overload matches this call.
>         Overload 1 of 2, '(start: number, deleteCount?: number | undefined): any[]', gave the following error.
>           Das Argument vom Typ "string" kann dem Parameter vom Typ "number" nicht zugewiesen werden.
>         Overload 2 of 2, '(start: number, deleteCount: number, ...items: any[]): any[]', gave the following error.
>           Das Argument vom Typ "string" kann dem Parameter vom Typ "number" nicht zugewiesen werden.

The Problems seems to be the "key" in line 5
But how can I solve that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `key` is a string, `splice` expects a number

Comment: @ritaj Seems to be so. But why?

Comment: This works fine: But is that realy the best way...?

if(favoritesArray[key].hidx === this.hidx && favoritesArray[key].kontenrahmen === this.kontenrahmen ) {
                var keynumber : number = parseInt(key);
                favoritesArray.splice(keynumber, 1);
                break;
            }

Comment: What do you mean why? Because `for ... in` returns a string indexer. Just add `parseInt` to `favoritesArray.splice(parseInt(key), 1);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting error because the syntax is not correct.
The following is syntax:

```
let arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
```

You can mention the start index, delete count: number of items to deleted and item1..itemN: To be added in the array.

You should specify the something like below:

```
favoritesArray.splice(parseInt(itemIndex), 1);
```

Since for..in returns key in string type and not number, you should parse to number and then use.

For more details, please refer documentation here [arraysplice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: "Since array type is Any, you should parse to number and then use." That doesn't matter. ANY array (pun intended) will return string keys from `for ... in` loop.

Comment: "You can not mention the element to delete from array using Splice" They weren't trying to. `for ... in` of array returns an array index, not an element.

Comment: @ritaj For..in returning type is string in this case. That's why, the user is getting error.

Comment: `for ... in` returns a string in ALL cases.

Comment: @ritaj so what is your point. Doesn't string need to be converted to number?